# AJAX not sending anything to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am serializing my form data, logging it, then sending it off to the PHP file, where is it returning null.

jQuery:

```
$('#preregister').submit(function () {


    if(checkemail("prereg_email")) {

        var data;

        data = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(data);

        $('#imageloader').fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/docs/adduser.php',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function ( data ) {
                //console.log(data); //returns a string of the data.
                var data = JSON.parse(data); //parses the string into an object.
                console.log(data); //logs the object.
                if (data.error) { alert(data.message); }
            }

        });

    }

      return false;
    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $Return = array();
    $Return["in"] = $_POST;
    $Return["error"] = false;
    $Return["message"] = "Nothing has happened.";

    /* EMAIL */
    $in_email = urldecode($_POST["prereg_email"]);
    $Return["in_email"] = $in_email;

    if (!filter_var($in_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        $Return["error"] = true;
        $Return["message"] = "Enter a valid email.";

    }

    if (!$in_email) {

        $Return["error"] = true;
        $Return["message"] = "Enter an email.";

    }


    str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($Return));
    echo json_encode($Return);

?>
```

When the data comes back, it says:

`Object {in: Array[0], error: true, message: "Enter an email.", in_email: ""}`

Which is odd, because right before I send data, I log it, and it reads:

`prereg_email=rbross3%40gmail.com`

So... I should at least be getting `$Return["prereg_email"]` right?

Comment: did you put `session_start();` on the top of your `adduser.php` file?

Comment: if you did, your `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` is probably not validating it because you have a `%40` in the place of the `@`

Comment: can you send us what you get from this  console.log(data);

Comment: @DanielX2010, `$in_email = urldecode($_POST["prereg_email"]);

And yes, session_start is in the global.php which is included.

Comment: @mbouzahir It's already above (the object)

Comment: Can you confirm `$_POST["prereg_email"]` is set. It's been a while, but I have a feeling it's `$_POST["data"]`. Simply add `print_r($POST);` to the start of your PHP file (after <?php) and let us know the output

Comment: @Graham Walters Its not, see... I am returning all of POST, and getting nothing back. `Return["in"] = print_r($POST);` gave me `in=true`. ODD.

Comment: Live version at: http://roseswap.com/

Comment: You can't set a variable = to `print_r($POST);`. Also, you'd be better off using GET. All you're sending is an email so the content length limit will NOT be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's because you are using `processData: false,`  try without it.
.serialize() returns a string already so you don't need processData: false,